# How to Stop automatic build trigger of Azure pipeline on Raising a Pull Request?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Trying to tackle pipeline poisoning in Azure pipeline. For which I need to stop the triggering of build pipeline whenever a pull request is Raised. One thing to note is that triggering part should not be controlled in pipeline configuration file because the attacker has access to make changes to pipeline config file.

- Was expecting to find some solution in Branch policies section or Repository settings, but was unable to find the required solution.
  [image]

These where the options available and can only add reviewers before merge which will not stop the triggering of pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot of the branch Policy, you are setting the Build Validation with the Pipeline: pipeline_veraible_display.

[image]

In this case, the pipeline will be automatically triggered when the Pull request is raised. This is the Pull Request Trigger feature in Azure DevOps.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [PR trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers)

> How to Stop automatic build trigger of Azure pipeline on Raising a Pull Request?

You can disable the Build Validation branch policy or set the Build Validation  as manual trigger.

For example:

[image]

When you raise the Pull Request, the build will not automatically trigger. You need to trigger it manually.

For example:

[image]

Comment: The only problem that I see is , if the user who has created the PR has access to Queue the build. Then it wont work. Can we ensure to restrict that ? Or can we Queue the pipeline as soon as the PR is approved ?

Comment: I can reproduce the same situation and fully understand your requirement. But if the user have the access to contribute to the Pull Request, he will have the access to queue the build. We are not able to restrict the permission to queue the build for the time being. One method is to disable the **Contribute to pull requests**  permission. But in this case, the users will have no access to create Pull Request.

Comment: For the requirement: Queue the pipeline as soon as the PR is approved, I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can achieve it. These two Branch policies are independently judged at this time.

Comment: The requirement is find a solution to tackle pipeline poisoning. i.e. When an attacker has access to pipeline configuration file (in azure pipeline) the attacker has the ability to fetch the credentials (Masked credentials from Pipeline Library in azure devops , Even the secrets from azure Key Vault https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#run-and-review-the-pipeline  ).  Need to find a solution for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you can add approvals in the Pipeline. You can navigate to **Pipeline Library -> Variable Group -> Approvals and checks**. or **Service connection ->  Approvals and checks**. Then when the Pipeline is running, it needs to be approved first.

Answer (score 1):

Add/edit this line in yml. Only scheduled and manual triggers will occur.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    exclude:
      - '*'
```

or if you want only to stop PR triggers, but keep ones upon PR complete to main:

```
trigger:
- main

pr:
  branches:
    exclude:
      - '*'
```

Comment: The above question is to stop the build trigger without making any changes to the code as it is in case of pipeline poisoning (we have assumed that the atacker has already access to the code).

Comment: thanks for clarification. just left it here in case someone does not have attackers and wish to stop triggering pipeline.